# How to add icons to a map that don’t conflict with another LineLayer [mapbox]

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-ios

I have an app where I have a Line Layer that outlines the borders of a user’s territory. I never want the bounds of my icon to intersect with the borders of the user’s territory

Currently i’m using a symbolLayer to display each of these icons but am open to using annotations / anything else if it works better for this situation. See below pictures for an example of what I have now vs. what I’d like to have.

[image]
[image]